# Yii 2 Class 'kartik\widgets\DepDrop' not found

Tags: yii2

подключаю http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop

через use kartik\widgets\DepDrop;

но получаю эту ошибку при

```
$form->field($model, 'subcat')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
    'options' => ['id' => 'subcat-id'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'depends' => ['cat-id'],
        'placeholder' => 'Select...',
        'url' => Url::to(['/site/subcat'])
    ]
]);
```

Comment: вроде полностью разобрался http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2016/01/yii-2-kartikdepdrop.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

дока его фигня полная

вот так сработало

```
 use kartik\depdrop\DepDrop;
```

Comment: он видимо просто не обновляет, по вашей ссылке в самом верху в блоке Important написано про вариант \kartik\depdrop\Depdrop, помнится он там все это раскидывать начинал по пакетам и с тех пор неймспейсы из примеров и поехали